# Image is showing even in false if-else statement in c#.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, image, if-statement

I am trying to show a image in a if-else statement in c#.net. if the statements is true it shows the image, but if the statement is false it shouldnt show image but mine is still showing the image. can anyone help me on it ASAP. Thanks

```
 if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
            StatusLabel.Text = "Location Found!!";
            StatusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
            DescLabel.Text = dr["Description"].ToString();
            String ImageFile = "Images\\" + dr["Image"];
            Map.ImageUrl = ImageFile;
            String ImageLoc = "IMap\\" + dr["MapImage"];
            MapImage.ImageUrl = ImageLoc;
        }
        else
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Location not found in the database";
            DescLabel.Text = "-";
            StatusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            String NotFound = "NoImage\\th.jpg";
            NoImage.ImageUrl = NotFound;
        }
```

Comment: Well what image is it showing, and in which control? Note that using PascalCase for local variables is pretty confusing IMO - normally local variables are camelCased.

Comment: What you mean by `it shouldnt show image`? Will show empty Image control or specific image which mean NOIMAGE or else?

Comment: @JonSkeet as you can see in the the else statement it shows "location not found in the database". that is where the it should show an image name not found. but mine is showing other image which should show in the if statement too.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan yes it should show a different image name notfound. but then its showing both images which is not found and image loc itself.

Comment: Image should be shown or text should be shown?

Comment: @RaajLokanathan: Sorry, your description of what is being shown is too confusing - it's not at all clear what you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
Map.Visible = false;
MapImage.Visible = false;
```

I suggest, if it possible, to use same control for both found and not found images.

Comment: i am sorry i am kinda new to c# can you where should i declare visibility function?